# how to prevent visual studio from messing with my code's identation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Basic 2010 automatically changes indentation of my code from this ::

```
public void fetchWebserviceCounters()  {
    csv = new StringBuilder();
    try  {
       Category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Web Service");
       foreach (String instance in Category.GetInstanceNames())  {
          counters = Category.GetCounters(instance);
          foreach (PerformanceCounter counter in counters)  {
              if (counter.CounterName == "Total Bytes Sent" | counter.CounterName == "Total Bytes Recieved") {
                 csv.Append(counter.CounterName + ",");
                 csv.Append(counter.NextValue().ToString() + ", ");
              }
          }
       }
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
   }
   Console.Write(csv.ToString());
```

}

to this

```
public void fetchWebserviceCounters()
    {
        csv = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            Category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Web Service");
            foreach (String instance in Category.GetInstanceNames())
            {
                counters = Category.GetCounters(instance);
                foreach (PerformanceCounter counter in counters)
                {
                    if (counter.CounterName == "Total Bytes Sent" | counter.CounterName == "Total Bytes Recieved")
                    {
                        csv.Append(counter.CounterName + ",");
                        csv.Append(counter.NextValue().ToString() + ", ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.Write(csv.ToString());
    }
```

**How can i prevent Visual Basic from Doing this to My code**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're passing C# to Visual Basic editor expect it to mess up.

There are lots of text formatting options in VS: Tools | Options | Text Editor | language | Formatting.

The extent of these depends on the language, and includes options about when code is automatically re-formatted.

Comment: Additional: The things you will need are grouped together at Tools | Options | Text Editor | language | Formatting | New Lines | New line options for braces.